# Module route with rewrite redirect to product on Prestahop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a custom route for an artist page:

```
public function hookModuleRoutes($params)
{
    return [
        'module-artists-artist' => [
            'controller' => 'artist',
            'rule' => 'artists/{id_artist}',
            'keywords' => [
                'id_artist' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_artist'],
            ],
            'params' => [
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'artists',
                'controller' => 'artist'
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

If I test with `/artists/1`, this works. But I want to add the `link_rewrite` property. So I modified the configuration like this:

```
public function hookModuleRoutes($params)
{
    return [
        'module-artists-artist' => [
            'controller' => 'artist',
            'rule' => 'artists/{id_artist}-{rewrite}',
            'keywords' => [
                'id_artist' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_artist'],
                'rewrite' => ['regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'],
            ],
            'params' => [
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'artists',
                'controller' => 'artist'
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

But when I try `/artists/1-baxter`, I'm redirected to the product page of product with ID `1`. My artist controller is never called.

```
[Debug] This page has moved
Please use the following URL instead: http://localhost:8000/fr/estampes/1-est-ce-que-etre
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because URLs generated by your pattern also match the product URL pattern, which has higherprecedence. PrestaShop doesn't check whether product exists, it just redirects directly to `ProductController`. Page patterns in PrestaShop differ from each other so that URLs can be quickly recognized to be associated with X controller. You can confirm this by checking the default patterns.

You can check the product URL pattern in back-office: SEO & URLs or in `DispatcherCore` class. Anyway, if you want an easy fix I'd suggest making this pattern:

`artists/{id_artist}/{rewrite}`

Comment: Thanks, it was this! But I was thinking custom url will be prior to default ones. So I made a `p-{id}-{rewrite}` for a product page and `a-{id}-{rewrite}` for artist page. Works great, thanks!